# How to get first date in series of versions

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I have a table "t1"

```
| Version | Date    | successor |
---------------------------------
| a       | 'day 1' | c         |
| b       | 'day 2' | e         |
| c       | 'day 3' |           |
| d       | 'day 4' |           |
| e       | 'day 5' | f         |
| f       | 'day 6' |           |
```

and I want to query every version with the earliest date in the series of versions (a series consists of a version and its successor - multiple chains possible). In this case it should output.

```
| Version | Date    | 
---------------------
| a       | 'day 1' |
| b       | 'day 2' |
| c       | 'day 1' |
| d       | 'day 4' |
| e       | 'day 2' |
| f       | 'day 2' |
```

I already tried it with a left join query of the same table, but in my case it outputted two dates in separate columns, but not one in one column (the earliest).

How does that work?

(Good solutions based on better table-design are also appreciated)

Comment: MS Access basically has no support at all for hierarchical or recursive queries.  I might suggest that you switch to a product that does, such as SQL Server Express or Postgres.

Comment: For additional possible designs you might want to Google Joe Celko. He wrote an entire book on modeling trees and hierarchies in relational databases and has posted much of the material online in user groups, etc. His book: http://www.amazon.com/Hierarchies-Smarties-Edition-Kaufmann-Management/dp/0123877334

Comment: Will you be running the query from within Access itself? If so, then you could use a VBA function to return the earliest date based on the [Version] of the current row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select version,(select date from t1 as b where a.version = b.successor) 
from    t1 as a
```

Comment: It seems, that this query outputs only the successor and the date of its predecessor, but not version with their own dates, which have no predecessor.